# Java > Count occurrence of null and 0 in JSON Response

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

I have a JSON response. I need to count values that are null and then values that are 0. The JSON looks something like:

```
   {
      “stuffA“:{“a”: {“b”: 1.12343, “c”: “2019-01-29”, “d”: null } },
      ”stuffB”:{ "e":{}, "f":{}, "g":{}},
      ”stuffC”:[ {"h":{}},{"i":{}} ],
      ”stuffD”:[ {“j”:{}},{“k”:{}},{“l”:{}},{“m”:{}}],
    }
```

I tried convert JSONObject to HashMap And look for frequency of null then 0 but doesn’t seem to work.

```
 map = (Map<String,Object>) gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());
 int count1 = Collections.frequency(map.values(), null);
 int count2 = Collections.frequency(map.values(), 0);
```

Am I going about this correctly or is there a more effective way?

Comment: Please show an example of json having null and 0 values. Also, share your attempt.

Comment: Updated. Let me know if need more info.

Comment: your json is not valid, for example in json we can not have such a ”stuffB”:{ {},{},{},{} } structure

Comment: @SaeedAlizadeh I updated the json structure

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean objectIsNull = yourJsonObject.isNull("stuffA");
```

you can try this inside a for

Answer (score 0):

first add following dependency to your **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.wnameless.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-flattener</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

first i transform json to a flat map object then count the count null and empty objects:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"stuffA\":{\"a\": {\"b\": 1.12343, \"c\": \"2019-01-29\", \"d\": null } },\n" +
                "  \"stuffB\":{ \"e\":{}, \"f\":{}, \"g\":{}},\n" +
                "  \"stuffC\":[ {\"h\":{}},{\"i\":{}} ],\n" +
                "  \"stuffD\":[ {\"j\":{}},{\"k\":{}},{\"l\":{}},{\"m\":{}}]\n" +
                "}";

        System.out.println(countZeroAndNull(json));
    }

    public static long countZeroAndNull(String json) {
        Map<String, Object> flattenJson = JsonFlattener.flattenAsMap(json);
        int count = 0;
        for (String s : flattenJson.keySet()) {
            if (flattenJson.get(s) == null) {
                count++;
            } else if (flattenJson.get(s) instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
                if (((LinkedHashMap) flattenJson.get(s)).size() < 1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

it your example it prints ***10*** as output